# Returning row names meet conditions from rle function

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing tree ring chronologies. The names of the lines are important because they are my years. I would like to obtain the rownames (years) for which a chronology (column) meets conditions of the type value below a threshold for at least a certain length of time. I tried the rle function which is interesting to check if my conditions are checked but not to know when the condition occurs.

```
df= my data frame
min_sup= ring width threshold
min_yr= the minimum time my ring width is below the min_value threshold
```

I tried several things like for example:

```
x=row.names(df)[with(rle(df[,1]< min_sup),lengths >= min_yr)]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show us a few entries of your data frame with an example of the expected output for those entries?

Comment: Thank you for you reply but I successfully arrived to find the solution.